# What factors should be considered to move to Amazon Storage?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

We have a Django application running on Webfaction. In this application, user uploads lot of images. So, far we have not had any issues. Soon, we expect about 10,000 users. But, I was wondering, should we decide to move to cloud solution like S3? How will the move help us?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of the advantages of moving to a remote storage such as S3 are:

1. Central storage location: You don't need to worry about managing a shared NFS mount as you bring up new webservers to handle additional load.
2. Offloading requests: Your servers will not take on the load of serving the media.

Some disadvantages are:

1. Additional cost: You pay for the storage and the bandwidth.
2. More moving parts: A file system is fairly easy to understand, manage and test. Remote APIs aren't perfect and some of the problems are out of your control.